# Iterating over parent elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iteration

I have some HTML that looks like this (sample 1):

```
<tr id="q_19030" class="q_grid " style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow;">
  <a class="reset-button" data-question-id="g_1363"></a>
</tr>
```

I also have some HTML that looks like this (sample 2):

```
<fieldset id="q_19044" class="q_default " style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow;">
  <a class="reset-button" data-question-id="q_19044"></a>
</fieldset>
```

I have some jQuery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.surveyor_radio').parent().parent().append('<a class="reset-button">Reset</a>');

  $('.reset-button').click(function () {
      $('#'+$(this).data('question-id') + ' input[type="radio"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
  });

  $('fieldset').each(function () {
      var qid = $(this).attr('id');
      $('.reset-button', $(this)).attr('data-question-id', qid);
  });
});
```

The jQuery code has three functions:

One adds a reset button to radio questions, another unchecks those questions once the reset button is clicked, while the third assigns the appropriate id number to the `data-question-id` attribute of the reset button.

### The Problem

The code in **sample 2** is correct where the `data-question-id` matches the id of its parent, the `fieldset id`.

The fieldset, however, does not always contain the correct `data-question-id` as indicated in **sample 1**, where it is an id of a particular row.

One assumption that can always be relied upon is that the correct id will always be the parent of the reset button.

### The Question

How do I appropriately iterate over each reset buttons parent, get its id, then set the `data-question-id` of the reset button.

My best attempt is something like `$(".reset-button").parent().each().attr("id");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the `.reset-button` elements, and set each `data-question-id` to the parents id :

```
$(".reset-button").each(function() {
    $(this).data('question-id', $(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Note that this will not change the data attribute when viewing it in a DOM inspector, as jQuery stores this internally, but will change the value thats later retrieved with `data();`

You could also do :

```
$(".reset-button").attr('data-question-id', function(i, val) {
    return this.parentNode.id || val;
});
```

Comment: I am most grateful to you, in 2 minutes you've solved what has taken me over three hours. It works great, I mostly understand what I was getting wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".reset-button").each(function() {
    var rid = $(this).parent().prop('id'); // get the parent ID
    $(this).data('question-id',rid); // set the data-question-id of the reset button 
});
```